# Google Sheets - text(year(A2),"yy") gives unexpected result

Tags: google-sheets-formula

cell A2 contains today's date, 6/1/2021

formula:

```
=text(year(A2),"yy")
```

I am expecting:

```
21
```

but instead I get:

```
05
```

In Google Docs help, https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en, the notes show "yy for the year as two digits."

And if I change formula to:

```
=text(year(A2),"yyyy")
```

I get:

```
1905
```

The following work as expected:

```
=text(month(A2),"00")
=text(day(A2),"00")
=year(A2)
```

with results:

```
06
01
2021
```

Why is the text(year) acting so unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `=text(A2,"yy")` is what you need.

Using `year` around `A2` converts the date to a 4 digit number, which is the issue when you try and use `text`.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Similarly, I can drop month() and day() in above examples, so those formulas simplify to: `=text(A2,"mm")` and `=text(A2,"dd")`